# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_rb_funcallv"

Tags: c, ruby, clang, llvm-clang

I'm trying to call Ruby from C, and for some reason I cannot execute `rb_funcall2` nor `rb_funcall3`. However `rb_funcall` works.

My example,

**Hello.c**

```
#include <ruby.h>

void hello_from_ruby()
{
  if (ruby_setup())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to init Ruby VM\n");
    }

    rb_require("/test");
    rb_funcall2(0, rb_intern("some_ruby_method"), 0, NULL);    

    ruby_cleanup(0);
  }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  hello_from_ruby();
  return 0;
}
```

**test.rb**

```
def some_ruby_method
  puts "Hello from ruby"
end
```

**Command that execute:**

```
clang hello.c  -o hello -I/opt/rubies/2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0  -I/opt/rubies/2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-darwin14.0  -lruby
```

**The exception:**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_rb_funcallv", referenced from:
      _hello_from_ruby in hello-190761.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

For some reason, only these two methods are not being linked.
Thanks

My question: How can I link `rb_funcall2` on my code

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm getting an exception, and I don't how to solve. I thought it was pretty clear

Comment: [This post](https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings/issues/72) should help. ryanmelt  answer points out that you must use ruby c-lang compiled.

Comment: Tried that before. It didn't work :( Thanks.

Comment: I get the same error, message. This is the content inside `../lib`: `libruby-static.a  libyaml-0.2.dylib libyaml.a         libyaml.dylib     libyaml.la        pkgconfig         ruby`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my Ruby was compiled using `gcc` so I had to recompile for clang:

```
CC=clang CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-gcc=clang --enable-shared" ruby-build 2.1.0 /opt/rubies/2.1.0
```

I figure it out after looking into this issue:https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings/issues/72

Thanks.